# How do i make jQuery unique ID for div for click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need on selection to append div element to the another div, I have done it, and also every time when I select new selection, it should append new div.

the problem is, those appended div's have same id, so I can not delete particular element. I have made them unique with declaring var and combining id with a string, like : `id="add_marke'+selectedKey+'"` BUT I cant do something like this `jQuery( "#add_marke'+selectedKey+'" ).click(function() {`

How can I select ID when I make unique ID?

```
var selectedKey = jQuery("#model").val();
jQuery('#example').append('' + '<div class="add_marke" id="add_marke' +
  selectedKey + '" >' +
  '   <div class="car_tag"><span  class="lbl"><span id="car_name" class="icon-remove"></span></div> ' +
  '&nbsp' +
  '   <select  name="model_cars" id="model_cars" ><option id="selectModel" name="selectModel" value="all" >Please select </option><option>test</option></select>' +
  '&nbsp' + '</div>');
jQuery("#car_name").click(function() {
  jQuery("#add_marke\\.selectedKey").remove();
});
```

Comment: Don't define click on id but whole class and check id in click event.
$(document).on('.add_marker', function(e) {...});

Comment: You can use jquery closest selector. give class name for button and give class name for main div. now do this thing. $('.buttonSelector').on('click',function(e){ $(this).closet('.parentDiv').remove()})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the IDs as you do with a predefined prefix:

```
... id="add_marke_' + selectedKey + '" ...
```

And then bind the click with a jQuery selector for all elements that have the ID **starting with** `add_marke_`:

```
$('div[id^="add_marke_"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add the click handler to the class name shared by all of these divs. Once the click handler has been triggered, you can then extract the relevant `id` of the element and compose a selector from that `id`.

```
jQuery( ".class_name" ).click(function() {
  var id = jQuery( this ).attr( "id" );
  jQuery( "#" + id ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
jQuery( ".icon-remove" ).click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: @Palec Thanks for your suggestion. I'll follow that now on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since an ID must be unique you have one of two options, as I see it:

1. Appending some sort of counter or numeric identifier to the ID, so you always have a unique ID (e.g., count the number of elements and then attribute your ID as `my-id-1`, `my-id-2`, etc.) Here you would have to write the DOM query in such a way that searches only for those IDs which begin with a given pattern, `div[id^="my-id-"]`
2. Use a `class` to identify the object in terms of any interactions you would like to provide for all of these `<div>` elements which have the same structure. Here, you can query based on a common class, in your case `.add_marke`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parentElement">
   <span>jagadeesh</span>
   <span class="icon-remove car-remove"></span>
   <button >Remove</button>
</div>

    $('.car-remove').on('click',function(){
        var mainElement = $(this).closest('.parentElement')
        /// do what ever you want with main element. it selects only current parent
        //element
        mainElement.remove();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Wg9FE/1/

```
var selectedKey = "someId";

jQuery('#example').append('' +
            '<div class="add_marke" id="add_marke'+selectedKey+'" >' +
            '   <div class="car_tag"><span  class="lbl"><div id="car_name" class="icon-remove"></div></div> ' + '&nbsp' +
            '   <select  name="model_cars" id="model_cars" ><option id="selectModel" name="selectModel" value="all" >Please select </option><option>test</option></select>'+ '&nbsp' +
            '</div>');

jQuery( "#car_name" ).click(function() {
             jQuery( "#add_marke" + selectedKey ).remove();
        });
```